# How to ensure ArcPy CalculateField expression runs if one or more input shapefiles from workspace are missing a field referenced in that expression?

Tags: python, arcpy, field-calculator, fields-attributes

I have a basic ArcPy script that reads an input folder of shapefiles, copies them to a separate output folder, defines this output folder as the workspace and then performs a `CalculateField` action, followed by `DeleteField` action.

The script runs without issues until it comes across a shapefile that does not contain a field referenced in the `CalculateField` expression, at which point the script stops. I have tried to account for this by adding the `lstFields` line and associated `if`/`try` statement, which results in the script running through but it now ignores the `CalculateField` expression all together but successfully deletes the required fields. Script is below:

```
# Import arcpy module

import arcpy
import os

# Local Variable

arcpy.env.workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
output = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#Copy shp files from original input directory to working output directory

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for shapefile in fcList:
    outFeatureClass = os.path.join(output,shapefile.strip(".shp"))
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(shapefile, outFeatureClass)

#Set workspace for edits

arcpy.env.workspace = output

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    lstFields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)

    if "SRC_NAME" in lstFields:
        try:
            # Process: Calculate SRT field value using SRC_NAME field if present
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "SRT", "30 if !SRC_NAME! == \"CHUM\" else 110", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
        except IndexError:
            continue

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    # Process: Delete required fields
    arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, "SRC_NAME;SPEC_ID;SRC_DATE;SCALE;Shape_Leng;Shape_Area;ID")
```

The field that is causing issues is `SRC_NAME`. This field is present in the majority of inputs and is used in the `CalculateField` expression to populate `SRT` field. Once this action is done `SRC_NAME` is then no longer required and therefore referenced in the `DeleteField` action. If `SRC_NAME` is not present in input shapefiles, then `SRT` value does not need to be calculated, but this lack of `SRC_NAME` is the cause of the issue. The `CalculateField` expression is directly from ArcMap Model Builder.

I am not sure if the `CalculateField` expression needs to be referenced as a loop or similar to address this issue or the use of `if`/`try` statements is the correct approach. Any advice/comments would be most welcome.

Edit

Using suggestions from comments the script now works. Updated code:

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    lstFields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]
    try:

        if "SRC_NAME" in lstFields:
  
        # Process: Calculate SRT field value using SRC_NAME field if present
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "SRT", "30 if !SRC_NAME! == \"CHUM\" else 110", "PYTHON_9.3", "")

        # Process: Delete required fields
            arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, "SRC_NAME;SPEC_ID;SRC_DATE;SCALE;Shape_Leng;Shape_Area;ID")

        if "SRC_NAME" not in lstFields:
            continue
    except IndexError:
            continue

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, "SRC_NAME;SPEC_ID;SRC_DATE;SCALE;Shape_Leng;Shape_Area;ID")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not 100% sure the Try is helping here. But I would say it doesn't look like you're dealing with the condition where `"SRC_NAME"` is NOT in `lstFields`.

I wonder does the below work? Using the else statement to catch these occurrences?

Also combines the calculate and delete together as I assume you only want the delete to occur if the calculation has happened? If not just take it back out.

```
#Set workspace for edits

arcpy.env.workspace = output

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    lstFields = arcpy.ListFields(fc)
    
    if "SRC_NAME" in lstFields:
        # Process: Calculate SRT field value using SRC_NAME field if present
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(fc, "SRT", "30 if !SRC_NAME! == \"CHUM\" else 110", "PYTHON_9.3", "")
        
        # Process: Delete required fields
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, "SRC_NAME;SPEC_ID;SRC_DATE;SCALE;Shape_Leng;Shape_Area;ID")
    if "SRC_NAME" not in lstFields:
        continue
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

Comment: The else statement makes more sense, but this fails to execute, flagging invalid syntax on line 35 -  except IndexError:

Comment: Try the revision I've just added. Where else becomes more specific if not...

Comment: This still flagged invalid syntax for except IndexError: I think this can't be included without associated 'try' statement. So I added 'try:' before the first 'if' statement in your code and the script ran through but neither CalculateField action or DeleteField action took place. I am thinking maybe arcpy.ListFields is the wrong approach?

Comment: [`ListFields()` returns field objects](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm), not their names directly.  You'd want to change that line to `lstFields = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(fc)]`

Comment: Updated the code using @mikewatt suggestion. Working script now included as edit to initial post